# Should equals() method of value objects strive to return true by using transformations of attributes?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Assume we have a value object `Duration` (with attributes `numberOfUnits`, `unit`). Would it be a good idea to treat these objects as equal (for example, overriding `Object.equals()`) if they have the same duration but different units? Should `1 min` be equal to `60 sec`.

There are many contradicting examples. With java's `BigDecimal` `compareTo() == 0` does not imply `equals() == true` (`new BigDecimal("0").equals(new BigDecimal("0.0"))` returns false). But `Duration.ofHours(24).equals(Duration.ofDays(1))` returns true.

Comment: None of us have the context you do on the domain you're working in, so we cannot tell you.

Comment: Well, `Duration` is quite a well known concept. When they implement `equals()` on `BigDecimal`, they also do not know the context in which it will be used, but they implement it anyway.

Comment: There might be a principle that usually works better more often than not: should it or shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

That's an unfortunately complicated question.

The simple answer is no: the important goal of value objects is to correctly model queries in your domain.

If it happens that `equals` in your domain has nice properties, then you should model them and everything is awesome.  But if you are modeling [something weird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) then getting it right trumps following the rules everywhere else.

Complications appear when your implementation language introduces contracts for `equals` that don't match the meaning in your domain.  Likely, you will need to invent a different spelling for the domain meaning.

In Java, there are a number of examples where [equals doesn't work as you would expect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), because [the hashCode contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) prohibits it.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I upvoted @jonrsharpe comment because without knowing the context it is almost impossible to give you an answer.

An example of what @jonrsharpe means could be that if in your domain you are using `Duration` VO to compare users input (who choose numberOfUnits and unit in a UI) it is obvious that `Duration` in minutes is not equal to `Duration` in seconds even if 1 min = 60 sec because you want to know if the users inputs the same things, and in this case they not.

Now, assuming that you will use `Duration` just for other things in which the format does not matter and ever means the same thing for domain rules (i.e. outdate something):

- Why do you need `Duration.unit` attribute if it gives you nothing of value in your domain?
- Why can not you just work with one unit type internally?

If it is just because different inputs/outputs in your system you should transform it to your internal/external(UI, REST API, etc) representation before apply rules, persist the VO (if needed) and/or showing it in a UI. So, separate input/output concerns from your domain. Maybe Duration (with unit attribue) is not a VO is just part of your ViewModel.